# Jackson : Filter null or blank values while converting json string response to pojo conversion using jackson

Tags: json, liferay, jackson, liferay-6, pojo

I am using jackson to convert jason response to List of pojo. Below is the response which I am getting.

```
[

    {
        "code": "",
        "total": 24,
        "name": null
    },
    {
        "code": "",
        "total": 1,
        "name": "Test"
    }
]
```

And I am converting it to the List of Pojo. Below is my pojo.

```
public class ItemCategory {

private String code;
private String name;
private String total;

public ItemCategory() {
}

public ItemCategory(final String code, final String name, final String total) {
    super();
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.total = total;
}

/**
 * @return the code
 */
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

/**
 * @param code
 *            the code to set
 */
public void setCode(final String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the count
 */
public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

/**
 * @param count
 *            the count to set
 */
public void setTotal(final String total) {
    this.total = total;
}
}
```

Everything works fine. But I want to remove the values to be converted to pojo which has code as blank/null value. i.e. "code": "", OR "code": null

I am using below jackson code to convert the json to pojo.

```
Object pojo = null;
try {
    pojo = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeReference);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    throw new InvalidPojoException(e.toString(), e);
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    throw new InvalidPojoException(e.toString(), e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new InvalidPojoException(e.toString(), e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new InvalidPojoException(e.toString(), e);
}
return pojo;
```

Using below code for json to object.

```
(List<ItemCategory>) JsonParserUtil.toPojo(serviceResponse.getStringResponse(),new TypeReference<List<ItemCategory>>(){});
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you mind setting the answer as accepted? thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to annotate your bean class like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(
include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL,
)
```

source: [JsonSerialize annotation javadoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html#include%28%29)

Comment: Thanks Michal for reply. Just to clarify would it simple remove the entire set of properties in which it has null value. Lets say from the mentioned response in my question, final serialized List<ItemCategory> should not include the first object with "total":24 as it has code with blank("") value. So the list will only has set of objects which has notnull/blank value for "code". And other set I don't want to be serialize to ItemCategory pojo. So I don't want to remove "code" property itself but the entire set which is having null/blank value for "code".

Comment: I don't think so, no, because, given a simple null check, the list elements themselves won't be null. As this is a bit more complex case, you should probably create your own serializer for the list object (I don't think that a serializer for ItemCategory class itself will suffice).

Comment: Thanks Michal. It gives me some direction to go ahead with.